# Rendering a Rubik's cube with mplot3d

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a representation of a Rubik's cube in Python, and I can get the colors of each face at any given time. I'm trying to use pyplot to render the cube in 3D. So far I've got the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# This import registers the 3D projection, but is otherwise unused.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import


# prepare some coordinates
x, y, z = np.indices((3, 3, 3))

cube1 = (x < 3) & (y < 3) & (z < 3)

# set the colors of each object
colors = np.empty(cube1.shape, dtype=object)
colors[cube1] = ['green']

# and plot everything
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(cube1, facecolors=colors, edgecolor='k')

plt.show()
```

This renders a green cube. I need to find a way to change the colors of each face on each voxel, but I can't figure out how the colors array works. I can't find any reference to it in the documentation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [This](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/voxels.html) looks very close to what you want.

Comment: @iamvegan: it's not closer... in a rubik's cube the FACES have different colors, not the little cubes. There are 8 corner cubes (with 3 colors each) and 12 edge cubes (2 colors each)

Comment: This can maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853563/how-can-i-paint-the-faces-of-a-cube

Comment: @6502  you're right, wirthra's link is more helpful.